# HoughLinesBinary doesn't find lines

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I use canny on image of a house and then `HoughLinesBinary` on result.

**Original image:**

[image]

**Image after canny:**

[image]

**Lines found by HoughLinesBinary:**

[image]

As you can see it produced many artifacts, but didn't mark straight lines, like the left side of the door

Source:

```
public static Image<Bgr, byte> split_to_patterns(Image<Bgr, byte> original)
{
    Image<Bgr, byte> res = original.Copy();
    LineSegment2D[] lines =
        original
        .Convert<Gray, byte>()
        .Canny(16, 16)
        .HoughLinesBinary(1,Math.PI/16,1,10,1)[0];
    foreach (LineSegment2D line in lines)
    {
        res.Draw(line,new Bgr(Color.Red),2);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: did you try to reduce the angle parameter?

Comment: You probably need to gaussian blur the image before canny (and find cleaner edges), and then play a little with Hough parameters

Comment: `LineSegment2D[] lines =
                original
                .Convert<Gray, byte>()
                //.SmoothGaussian(3)
                .Canny(16, 16)
                .HoughLinesBinary(0.01,Math.PI/180,4,10,1)[0];`            does not find the left  side of the door whether blur commented or not. This side is defined by straight white vertical line without breaks.